# Как изменить размер выходного слоя?

Tags: python, keras

Увлекся изучением рекурентных нейронных сетей. Собственно вопрос: Есть данные `X` и `y`. Размерность `X`: `(1000, 20, 4)` `y`: `(1000, 5, 4)`. Данные синтетические (сгенерированное случайное блуждание).
Модель имеет вид:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(output_dim=100, return_sequences=True, 
               activation='elu', input_dim=4))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=4))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam(clipnorm=1.0),
              metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
```

Как сделать так, чтобы модель выдавала на выходе массив такой же формы как в `y` `(5, 4)`? В данном примере модель выдает на выход массив формой `(20, 4)` т.е. такой же формы как и `X`.

Функция нарезающая dataset:

```
def make_dataset(data, steps, shift=1):
    X = []
    y = []
    for i in range(data.shape[0] - steps - shift + 1):
        X.append(data[i:i + steps])
        y.append(data[i + steps:i + steps + shift])
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)
```

Функция принимает на вход двумерный массив размерностью `n_timesteps` x `n_features`.

Comment: можете объяснить почему `y` имеет такую размерность?

Comment: Добавил ф-цию нарезающую датасет. X[i] представляет собой массив размером n_steps x n_features, а y[i] - это просто сдвиг относительно конца текущего X[i] на shift шагов в будующее. Вот я и пытаюсь понять можно ли так сделать. И если нет, то почему.

Comment: по-моему, в этом случае модель будет намного сложнее - `LSTM` нейроны будут использоваться многократно для вычисления весов каждого последующего `timestep` и на вход им подается вывод предыдущего шага. [Вот пример](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-network-python/)

Comment: Так может нужно ввести функцию преобразования 1000/20/5 к 1000/5/4. У вас просто отсутствует преобразование как таковое. Примерно как вектор 2х2 преобразовать в вектор 1х4